# Delayed job, undefined method `taskmy' for class `Batch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, delayed-job

I am trying to use delayed_job to run some code in background and give the user some response immediately.

```
class Batch

  def self.taskmy
    # some very long task
  end
  def taskmy
      self.taskmy
  end
  handle_asynchronously :taskmy
end
```

**My controller action look like below**

```
def send_command
    count = 0
    count2 = 0
    Batch.delay.taskmy
    puts count
    puts count2
end
```

**But i get an error**

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with id primary > > found

I started the job with

```
rake jobs:work
```

Comment: did you restart delayed_job worker?

Comment: how do i do that? and do i have to do this every time in production too?

Comment: ain't you running any worker like `rake jobs:work`? where did you get the error then?

Comment: i am just calling delay before the method name.

Comment: on which line exactly are you getting the error? Try restarting your server..

Comment: i updated the code, and started tje job. but get different error
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with id primary > > found

Comment: well, that's a different error altogether...try commenting/uncommenting mongo gem and start server or google for other solutions..you probably need to configure `database.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the active record gem with mongodb.
i included following in my gemfile and restarted the job.
gem 'delayed_job_mongoid'